# UIImagePickerController difference between isSourceTypeAvailable: and isCameraDeviceAvailable:

Tags: ios, ipad

In `UIImagePickerController`, what is the difference between using `isSourceTypeAvailable:` and `isCameraDeviceAvailable:` when determining whether the camera is available?

Answer (score 1):

source type = photo library / camera / saved photos album

camera device = front / rear

Answer (score 0):

`isSourceTypeAvailable:` Verify that the device is capable of picking content from the desired source. where as

`isCameraDeviceAvailable:` returns YES if the camera indicated by cameraDevice is available, or NO if it is not available

Answer (score 0):

## using `isCameraDeviceAvailable` is probably better

The [older, (probably most influential) documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010406) uses `isSourceTypeAvailable`. Most of the discussion in stack overflow seems to use it exclusively.

But you should also check for the specific camera you plan to use, the default is `rear`. The reason why I think you should check is:

- The documentation is unclear on whether `isSourceAvailable` returns `true` when only one camera is available. So it could say yes because front is avilable, and try to send you to rear.
- The documentation is unclear on what real world conditions cause a camera to be un-available (I'm trying figure out steps so I can test this...)
- The default is "rear", so why not explicitly test for `rear`?

Here's some examples:

```
  //        SOURCETYPE
    if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
        print ("no camera!")
    } else {
        print ("happycam!")
    }
 //        CAMERA TYPES
    if !UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(UIImagePickerController.CameraDevice.rear){
        print ("no rear camera!")
    } else {
        print ("rear camera available!")
    }
    if !UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(UIImagePickerController.CameraDevice.front){
        print ("no front camera!")
    } else {
        print ("front camera available!")
    }
```